# How make label move up on hover or active in a login form

Tags: html, css

I displayed my label on input with position absolute. I know want the label to move up when the user clicks on the input.

```
<div id="signIn">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <div class="email">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="uname" required>
        </div>
        <div class="pass">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="psw" required>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: show what you desire.

Comment: Like in Material UI ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this snippet. This performs the desired operation as in the MaterialUI.

```css
.form-field {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
}

.form-field label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 8px;
  top: 8px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  z-index: -2;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.form-field input {
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.form-field input:focus + label, input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ label {
  top: -20px;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div id="signIn">
  <h2>Login</h2>
  <div class="form-field email">
    <input type="text" placeholder=" " name="uname" required />
    <label>Email</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-field pass">
    <input type="password" placeholder=" " name="psw" required>
    <label>Password</label>
</div>
</div>
```

EDIT

By checking if the placeholder is visible/hidden, you can keep the label on top as if it is focused.

In the edited snippet, I have added an empty string as placeholder and checking if it is visible/hidden (placeholder will be gone once we type something in the input).

Comment: This worked, thx. Another question? how do I make the label stay up so when the user types or changes input it doesn't go down?

Comment: @Kiro, I have updated the snippet with the desired functionality. I am checking the existence of placeholder. Kindly check the update in the Answer. Also do let me know if anything more required.